# tikzpicture pushes my two columns of minipage to next page

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates

I'm new to LaTex and I'm trying to complete my cv.
I have a two-column design (Overleaf deedy-resume) made out of two minipage.
Now I would like to insert my picture in the top right corner but when I do it, it pushes down all the rest to the next page.

[image: Left: before inserting my picture, right: after insertion]

Here's my code (with the picture):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{deedy-resume}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\Huge \textbf{ADRIEN SIMON}\\*
\begin{small} 
%\color{darkgray} \color{gray}
some text\\
\end{small}
\end{flushleft}

%This is the picture I wish to place in the top right corner
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]  at (current page text area.north east)
{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{_I9A6002-2.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LEFT COLUMN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\textwidth}
\sectionspace
\section{Computer skills}
some text\\
\sectionspace
\section{Languages}
some text\\
\sectionspace
\section{Certificates}
some text\\
\sectionspace
\section{Relevant}
\vspace{-1.5mm}
\section{Coursework}
some courses\\
\end{minipage} 
\hfill

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RIGHT COLUMN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.67\textwidth} 
\sectionspace 
\section{Education}
\some text\\
\sectionspace
\section{Academic Projects}
\some text\\
\sectionspace
\section{Work Experience}
some text\\
\sectionspace 
\section{Extracurricular Experience} 
some text\\
\sectionspace 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try `\end{tikzpicture}%`, note the trailing `%`!

Comment: Did you compile _twice_?

Comment: You should never attempt to modify these so called "templates".  They are only meant to replace their content with your.  Any modification is out of scope.